# Vue JS form issue - mutating vuex store state outside handlers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am currently getting the `[vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers` error only when I try to edit the form, if I am posting a new plugin it works fine. From [this](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html) doc I'm not sure where I'm going wrong - while I fetch the plugin from vuex, I try to give the local state those values and then leave vuex alone. Ideally once fetched vuex, I wouldn't need to touch it again until the form is submitted. But I'm not sure what is causing the error exactly

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h4>{{this.$route.query.mode==="new"?"New":"Edit"}} Plugin</h4>
        <form class="">
            <label>Id</label>
            <input :value="plugin.id" class="" type="text" @input="updateId">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input :value="plugin.name" class="" type="text" @input="updateName">
            <label>Description</label>
            <textarea :value="plugin.description" class="" type="text" @input="updateDescription"></textarea>
            <label>Version</label>
            <input :value="plugin.version" class="" type="text" @input="updateVersion">
            <button type="submit" @click.prevent="submitForm">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import util from '~/assets/js/util'
export default {
    created() {
        if (this.mode === 'edit') {
            this.plugin = this.$store.state.currentLicence.associatedPlugins.find(p => p.pluginId === this.$route.query.pluginId)
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateId(v) {
            this.plugin.id = v.target.value
        },
        updateName(v) {
            this.plugin.name = v.target.value
        },
        updateDescription(v) {
            this.plugin.description = v.target.value
        },
        updateVersion(v) {
            this.plugin.version = v.target.value
        }
    },
    computed: {
        mode() { return this.$route.query.mode }
    },
    data: () => ({
        plugin: {
            id: null,
            name: null,
            description: null,
            version: null
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

Thanks for any help, clearly my understanding of the way that vuex and local state are handled is flawed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are editing the state directly.

`this.plugin = this.$store.state.currentLicence.associatedPlugins.find(p => p.pluginId === this.$route.query.pluginId)` - this is exactly this part of code where you put the object from the store directly into the data, therefore by editing the field you are directly editing the state. Don't do that!

You should always use stuff like (I am not sure how nested computed will work but I don't think you have to nest it):

```
computed: {
  plugin: {
    id: {
      get () { // get it from store }
      set (value) { // dispatch the mutation with the new data } 
    }
  }
}
```

There is a nice package whill will do most work for you: https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields . You can use it to semi-automatic generate computed with getters and setters for each field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I hadn't realised I was mutating the store directly because of the created instance. I found that if I changed that line to `this.plugin = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.currentLicence.associatedPlugins.find(p => p.pluginId === this.$route.query.pluginId)))` I could use v-model throughout all my form inputs without having the extra code of the get and set methods. It works fine, not sure if there are any down sides to this approach though?

Comment: The 'only' downside is that you do not have current edited state in Vuex, however it can be beneficial sometimes so it depends on your use case.

Comment: Ahhh ok, the nature of the project means I need to be fetching from the backend regularly anyway, so it shouldn't be a problem in this case. Thanks for the help mate

Comment: glad I helped :)